# get responseText in ajax

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, object

I just want to get ajax feedback

```
var result = $.ajax({
                url : 'linkAPI',
                type : 'get',
                dataType: 'JSON'
            });
            console.log(result);
```

and only responseTEXT appears.

```
Console.log(result.responseText);
```

// undefined

Answer (score 0):

You should log it in the success callback of AJAX as it is an asynchronous operation.

```js
$.ajax({
    url : 'linkAPI',
    type : 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }
});
```